# How to get a Mathplotlib to follow size changes of a surrounding tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The idea is to create a small viewer for a specific .csv file. All the development work is done, BUT the mathplotlib graph does not resize if the main window is resized.

What is the missing code to make the graph following the size of the main window?

Below is a squeezed down example of my program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import datetime
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
import pandas as pd


class AppWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.notebook = None
        self.df = None
        self.df_1 = None
        self.build_app_window()

    def build_app_window(self):
        self.title("env_viewer")

        btn_refresh = tk.Button(self,
                                text="Aktualisieren",
                                command=self.refresh)
        btn_refresh.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="new", padx=5)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=10, sticky="nsew")

        self.add_voltage_tab()

    def add_voltage_tab(self):
        # the figure that will contain the plot
        self.fig_voltage, self.ax_voltage = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2.7),
                                                         dpi=50)
        # creating the Tkinter canvas, containing the Matplotlib figure
        self.canvas_voltage = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig_voltage,
                                                master=self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.canvas_voltage.get_tk_widget(),
                          text='Spannung')

    def update_voltage_plot(self):
        # Extract the data
        dates = self.df['Date Time']
        voltage = self.df['Voltage[V]']
        # redraw
        self.ax_voltage.clear()
        self.ax_voltage.plot(dates, voltage, color="blue", label="Spannung [V]")
        self.ax_voltage.legend(loc='upper left')
        self.fig_voltage.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
        self.fig_voltage.tight_layout()
        self.canvas_voltage.draw()

    def refresh(self):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.filepath_1 = os.path.join(dir_path, "2023-07_environment_data.csv")
        self.df_1 = pd.read_csv(str(self.filepath_1), sep=';')
        self.update_df()
        self.update_voltage_plot()

    def update_df(self):
        # Merge the data
        self.df = self.df_1
        # Convert the date column to datetime
        self.df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['Date Time'])
        # Sort the dataset in the ascending order of date
        self.df = self.df.sort_values(by='Date Time')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = AppWindow()
    MainWindow.mainloop()
```

Data sample

```
Date Time;in_temp;in_press;in_hum;out_temp;out_hum;Water;Fan1;Fan2;CPU_temp;Voltage[V];Current[mA];Power[W]
2023-07-05 07:15:02;23.39;951.55;52.74;22.12;63.41;898;0;0;48.69;14.30;391.98;5.613
2023-07-05 07:30:01;23.53;951.53;52.08;21.86;63.56;896;0;0;49.17;14.30;366.46;5.258
2023-07-05 07:45:02;23.56;951.46;52.63;21.70;65.56;899;0;0;50.15;13.72;380.67;5.547
2023-07-05 08:00:02;23.58;951.49;52.72;21.67;65.64;892;0;0;46.74;13.72;380.67;5.175
2023-07-05 08:15:02;23.61;951.29;52.81;21.59;65.65;891;0;0;49.17;13.72;379.79;5.198
2023-07-05 08:30:01;23.69;951.40;52.79;21.77;65.80;891;0;0;51.61;13.75;444.48;6.189
2023-07-05 08:45:02;23.69;951.60;52.60;21.80;65.27;899;0;0;52.09;13.75;444.88;6.170
2023-07-05 09:00:02;23.72;951.85;53.18;21.88;65.97;904;0;0;50.15;13.98;642.47;8.929
2023-07-05 09:15:02;23.80;952.10;53.61;21.79;67.41;898;0;0;50.15;13.68;382.56;5.201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'bind' method.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import pandas as pd


class AppWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.notebook = None
        self.df = None
        self.df_1 = None
        self.build_app_window()

    def build_app_window(self):
        self.title("env_viewer")
        self.geometry("800x600")  # Set the initial size of the main window

        # Bind the main window's <Configure> event to the on_resize callback
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)

        btn_refresh = tk.Button(self,
                                text="Aktualisieren",
                                command=self.refresh)
        btn_refresh.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="new", padx=5)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=10, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")

        self.add_voltage_tab()

    def on_resize(self, event):
        # Callback function to update graph size on main window resize
        width = event.width - 100
        height = event.height - 100
        self.fig_voltage.set_size_inches(width / 100, height / 100)
        self.canvas_voltage.draw()

    def add_voltage_tab(self):
        # the figure that will contain the plot
        self.fig_voltage, self.ax_voltage = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2.7),
                                                         dpi=100)  # Set the initial size of the graph
        # creating the Tkinter canvas, containing the Matplotlib figure
        self.canvas_voltage = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig_voltage,
                                                master=self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.canvas_voltage.get_tk_widget(),
                          text='Spannung')

    # Rest of your code ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = AppWindow()
    MainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Technoed does solve the issue with the canvas resizing.

But additional lines are necessary to get the surrounding notebook resizing properly as well:

```
def build_app_window(self):
    ...
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    ...
```

And the width and heigth should be integers:

```
self.fig_voltage.set_size_inches(int(width / 100), int(height / 100))
```